# Python pdfkit can't find wkhtmltopdf executable

Tags: python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

a few months ago I had created a little script to convert URLs to PDF files, this morning I tried to convert another link but I got this error from py prompt:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 24, in from_url
configuration=configuration, cover_first=cover_first)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 42, in __init__
self.configuration = (Configuration() if configuration is None
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 27, in __init__
'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
IOError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: ""
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - 
https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

I've googled a lot but still can't find solution. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I don't know why but python was replacing my environment path "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin" with "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdin" because of "\b" so I just replaced "\b" with "/b" and solved.